# Consecutive Primes mod 3

Tags: st.statistics, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem

Is anything known asymptotically about the binary "primes mod 3" sequence besides Dirichlet's result that 1 and 2 occur half of the time?  For example, can you prove that it does not eventually cycle forever with a simple "12" repetition?

(I would guess that this sequence is asymptotically random with no correlations, but it really wouldn't be that surprising if, for example, there were some tendency to switch back and forth in consecutive terms.  If anyone has an argument, or data, indicating that this sequence is not so random, I'd like to hear about it.)

Comment: See the discussion in the comments of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153656/sums-of-primes-that-are-themselves-prime .  It addresses essentially questions of your flavor.  Not too much is probably known about the complexity of this sequence, but recent progress on primes would say something as Terry Tao indicates in these comments.

Comment: One more comment: Work of Daniel Shiu shows that arbitrarily long strings of consecutive $1$'s (or consecutive $2$'s) will appear in this sequence.  In particular this rules out the $12$ cycling forever.  See also the recent preprint of Banks et al: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.7003v2.pdf .

Comment: Is Shiu's result based on hypothesis or pure theory?  I can't find the reference from Google and want to try to understand if this is proven with no assumptions.

Comment: Shiu's result is an unconditional theorem.  The preprint of Banks et al linked above gives the reference (and also a different proof of Shiu's result based on Maynard's recent work).

Comment: There is a very nice overview paper about these types of problems by Granville and Martin http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408319 A quite simlar question got ask for mod 4 istead of mod 3 http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128079/a-bit-of-primes

Comment: Just considering consecutive pairs, has anyone proven that there is no asymptotic correlation?  For example, is it impossible to have "21" and "12" each occur with a 30% rate, and "11" and "22" each occur with a 20% rate?

Comment: @bobuhito: No I don't think we can (provably) rule out the probabilities that you mention.

Comment: If I extrapolate from what Greg Martin said on the question I mentioned correctly it seems reasonable to expect that two consecutive are *slightly* less frequent than a change.

Comment: @quid As Greg said there, that effect goes to zero for large primes, so it wouldn't apply here (I'm looking for effects that stay finite in the asymptotic limit).

Comment: This is what I meant to convey by stressing the slightly. I am not sure how I am supposed to know it "wouldn't apply here"; if you exclusively care about the relative densities (assuming they exist) you could have said so.

Comment: @quid See recent paper [Unexpected biases in the distribution of consecutive primes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720) by Oliver and Soundararajan (I first mentioned it in a comment to Stopple's answer but had not read your last comment here carefully).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen it is quite pertinent here, indeed. Thanks for adding it. To put this in context, the paper shows that the "slight" I said is not as slight as one might expected (and I assumed then). While in a way it is still only  a slight effect.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the paper Chebyshev's Bias by Rubinstein and Sarnak, see also

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias

They show that in the sense of logarithmic density

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Other_density_functions

primes congruent to 2 modulo 3 predominate.  Specifically, and under certain hypotheses,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log x}\sum_{n<x,\pi(1,3,n)<\pi(2,3,n)}\frac{1}{n}\sim 0.9990\ldots,
$$
where $\pi(a,b,x)$ counts the number of primes less that $x$ congruent to $a$ modulo $b$

Comment: Interesting.  Let's say the sequence is "1212222121221111122..." from which I naturally calculate a "predomination sequence", P, as "1111222222222222112...".  I can't use your summation (since the starting prime is considered secret), but I suppose that I could calculate the average P and see that it is greater than, for
example, 1.501, even as my starting secret prime goes to infinity.  Of course, this is all based on hypotheses, so I wonder if someone has tried to measure this limit.

Comment: @bobuhito Apparently a new discovery is that $p_{n+1}$ modulo 3 is strongly correlated to $p_n$ modulo 3. The same goes for other small moduli. See [Mathematicians Discover Prime Conspiracy](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20160313-mathematicians-discover-prime-conspiracy/).

Comment: @Jeppe I think this discovery is the "slight" effect already mentioned in comments.

Comment: @bobuhito You are right. Now I included it in a comment to the question as well (hopefully I am not being too redundant).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen does this hold only modulo 3? What about other primes?

Comment: @Alephnull The same modulo other primes.